# QEMU boot from snapshot giving error

Tags: virtualization, boot, snapshot, qemu, kvm

I am trying to boot QEMU from its snapshotted image. I use the following command on **QEMU Monitor**

`stop
savevm new
cont`

I then exit from **QEMU Montor**.

Then I look at the list of snapshots that have been created for the QCOW2 base file:

`:~/qemu-2.0.0-rc0$ qemu-img snapshot -l ~/ubuntu-kvm/ubuntu.qcow2 
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG                 VM SIZE                DATE       VM CLOCK
1         new                   85M 2014-04-14 20:31:07   00:06:01.902`

I now want to boot the Guest VM from the snapshot "new".

For this I did:

`./x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -hda ~/ubuntu-kvm/ubuntu.qcow2 -loadvm new`

however I got this error:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5751fb6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
0  0x00007ffff5751fb6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
1  0x00007ffff7e07ec9 in tlb_flush (cpu=, flush_global=)
    at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:85
2  0x00007ffff7e0ca2c in cpu_common_post_load (opaque=, version_id=)
    at /home/manan/qemu-2.0.0-rc0/exec.c:423
3  0x00007ffff7e00d2d in vmstate_load_state (f=0x7ffff8ad1400, vmsd=0x7ffff82c9660, opaque=0x7ffff8971570, version_id=1)
    at vmstate.c:87
4  0x00007ffff7e719d7 in vmstate_load (version_id=, se=0x7ffff89821e0, f=0x7ffff8ad1400)
    at /home/manan/qemu-2.0.0-rc0/savevm.c:435
5  qemu_loadvm_state (f=0x7ffff8ad1400) at /home/manan/qemu-2.0.0-rc0/savevm.c:805
6  0x00007ffff7e7227a in load_vmstate (name=) at /home/manan/qemu-2.0.0-rc0/savevm.c:1091
7  0x00007ffff7c5ab5c in main (argc=, argv=, envp=) at vl.c:4457`

Am I missing some step during creating / loading the snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know from one of the posts that the problem lies with qemu-2.0.rc version itself. The segfault does not appear with qemu-1.7.0 version.